# How can I make a guard move out of the way?

Tags: fallout

I just went to Junktown to buy some rope so I could get down to the third level of Vault 15. The things that happen there happened, and now there's a guard standing in front of the only door, and he won't move for hell or high water.

Aside from shooting the guard and getting my level three butt kicked, how can I get out of there and continue with my game?

Comment: Have you already tried waiting?

Comment: I have, yes, at least for a day. Killian moves around, but the guard stays put.

Comment: Why don't you MacGyver your way out of there?

Comment: I'm tempted to vote to close this, since being in a room with Richard Dean Anderson is generally not a problem that needs a solution!

Comment: Tagged: every game freaking ever... =\

Comment: Original title was way better... otherwise I probably wouldn't have looked.

Comment: @spudone I agree. Especially since the opening remark was changed to no longer be funny, and is now simply useless. Boooooooo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was that Ian was standing in front of the door trying to get to me, which stopped the guard from leaving. Moving over to the other part of the shop caused Ian to move out of the way, which fixed everything (I robbed Killian blind anyway).

He didn't move the first time I went over there, so it may be that you need to save and reload the game a few times to make it happen.

Comment: As a side-note, the guards don't care if you steal anything, and Killian won't mind if you pick his pockets if it's after-hours. You can also pick the lock on his safe while he's standing right there. I love old games.

Answer (score 6):

Attempt (and fail) to steal something from the store.  Killian will talk to you and then throw you in jail.  After waiting for 24 hours, you will be free to continue exploring Junktown.

Comment: Won't I get a reputation hit for that?

Comment: Possibly.  It's pretty small if it is, as I accidentally ended up in jail, but was able to continue on (as a good guy) after serving my time.

Comment: Hell, I stole the rope 'cos he wouldn't sell it to me, so I guess I've already surrendered the moral high ground.